# VS Code log into container as specific user

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I built a Debian 10 sandbox container where I could play with my code bases. I added a user to maintain a permission wall between sudo commands typed too quickly with

```
USER ELDUDE
```

in the `Dockerfile`. However, when I build the container with that user as default login option VS Code fails to connect to the container with

```
Error: stream ended with:124 but wanted 1128865906
```

This is the initial error that brought me down this path.

If I do not specify the default user in the `Dockerfile` I can connect fine but VSCode server in the container runs as `root`. Now, that becomes a mess with file permissions etc if I start working on stuff.

Any idea what is going on? Can I set user names when I log into a container?
I also thought of enabling SSH on the container and connect through VS SSH but that failed thus far...

Comment: You don't "log in" to a container, but if you `docker exec` a debugging shell you can use a `-u` option to pick an arbitrary user for it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm wondering how this can be set within VS Code connecting into the container. This is just a missery attempt that my company is blocking VMs in their windows machines. Sucks. I now resorted to using `root` user only and it works, so I guess this is a VS Code container bug